# How to use `assign()` or `get()` on specific named column of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, assign, named

Is there a way to assign a value to a specific column within a data frame? e.g.,

```
dat2 = data.frame(c1 = 101:149, VAR1 = 151:200)    
j = "dat2[,"VAR1"]"  ## or, j = "dat2[,2]"
assign(j,1:50)
```

The approach above doesn't work.  Neither does this:

```
j = "dat2"
assign(get(j)[,"VAR1"],1:50)
```

Comment: You'll need to expand a little more on why you would do this. you can use `foo='VAR1'; dat2[,foo]<-1:50` instead and still pass your strings around if you're so moved.

Comment: Why? -- to create a bunch of arbitrarily named data frames, and populate a specific column in them.  I understand it is preferable to use a list structure for this; however, it would be useful to have another option.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

lets assume that we have a *valid* data.frame with 50 rows in each

```
dat2 <- data.frame(c1 = 1:50, VAR1 = 51:100)
```

1 . Don't use `assign` and `get` if you can avoid it.

`"dat2[,"VAR1"]"` is not valid in `R`.

You can also note this from the help page for `assign`

> assign does not dispatch assignment methods, so it cannot be used to
>   set elements of vectors, names, attributes, etc.
>
> Note that assignment to an attached list or data frame changes the
>   attached copy and not the original object: see attach and with.

A column of a data.frame is an element of a list

What you are looking for is `[[<-`

```
# assign the values from column (named element of the list) `VAR1`
j <- dat2[['VAR1']]
```

If you want to assign new values to `VAR1` within `dat2`,

```
dat2[['VAR1']] <- 1:50
```

---

### The answer to your question....

To manipulate entirely using character strings using `get` and `assign`

```
assign('dat2', `[[<-`(get('dat2'), 'VAR1', value = 2:51))
```

---

### Other approaches

#### data.table::set

if you want to assign by reference within a `data.frame` or `data.table` (replacing an existing column only) then `set` from the `data.table` package works (even with `data.frames`)

```
library(data.table)
set(dat2, j = 'VAR1', value = 5:54)
```

---

#### `eval` and `bquote`

```
dat1 <- data.frame(x=1:5)
dat2 <- data.frame(x=2:6)



for(x in sapply(c('dat1','dat2'),as.name)) {
  eval(bquote(.(x)[['VAR1']] <- 2:6))
}
```

---

#### `eapply`

Or if you use a separate environment

```
ee <- new.env()
ee$dat1 <- dat1
ee$dat2 <- dat2

# eapply returns a list, so use list2env to assign back to ee
list2env(eapply(ee, `[[<-`, 'y', value =1:5), envir = ee)
```

---

Comment: Don't forget `dat[, "VAR1"]`.

Comment: @krlmlr -- I prefer `[[<-` for single assignments.

Comment: Keep in mind that the thrust of my question has to do with get/assign -- in other words, I want to name and refer to the data frame by a character value.  I think `set()` will work in this way, just have to replace `set(dat2, ...)` with `set(get(), ...)`.  Thanks.

Comment: @baha-kev -- set will not create a column, only replacing values in existing columns

Comment: Huh? `set` is not a function in base or recommended R packages.

Comment: @DWin -- the text mentions `data.table`, forgot the explicit call to `library(data.table)`.... Its there now.

Comment: Your last "really ugly" approach is what I was looking for.  If you could move it to the top of your answer, that would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
set2 <- function(x,  val) {
   eval.parent(substitute(x <- val))
 }

> dat2 = data.frame(c1 = 101:150, VAR1 = 151:200)
> set2(dat2[["VAR1"]], 1:50)
> str(dat2)
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ c1  : int  101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 ...
 $ VAR1: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```